# Simple jQuery .mousewheel function not getting called on site but works in fiddle?

Tags: jquery, jsfiddle, mousewheel

This is pretty cut and dry - I'm trying to call a jQuery function that just triggers an `alert();` but I can't figure out why it's not working. Works in fiddle though... For some odd reason. I know this is sloppy but I'm going to give you guys the entire code for this page (it's not a lot) because I can't figure out why it works in fiddle but not on my site.

**Update:** Cut and pasted entire contents of mousewheel file into this page instead of referencing it. Still doesn't work. The problem is not in the path to the script or the way I'm referencing it. The problem is elsewhere...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html, body {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

        // In this case, I didn't want a scrollbar, so I used overflow: hidden. The container element is more essential than ever, though. The body element will not do.
        div.horizontal {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: static;
        }

        .table {
            display: table;
            table-layout: fixed;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .table > section {
            width: 1600px; // The width is based on my monitor. It's replaced by jQuery anyway. Percentage widths do not work.
            height: 100%;
            display: table-cell;
            background: #e3e3e3;
            vertical-align: middle;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js?ver=1.3.2'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/DigitalBrent/scripts/mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function ($) {
        $("body").mousewheel(function (event, delta) {
            alert('hello');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="horizontal">
        <div class="table">
            <section>
                <h1>Full-Screen Horizontal Layouts</h1>
                <p>Made with <code>display: table-cell;</code></p>
                <p>By Ezequiel Bruni</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h1>Full-Screen Horizontal Layouts</h1>
                <p>Made with <code>display: table-cell;</code></p>
                <p>By Ezequiel Bruni</p>
            </section>
            <section>
                <h1>Full-Screen Horizontal Layouts</h1>
                <p>Made with <code>display: table-cell;</code></p>
                <p>By Ezequiel Bruni</p>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Shouldn't this trigger an alert when the user scrolls? Why is this not working? I have no errors in the console.

Here's a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/ekmpwjhh/2/

Comment: `http://localhost:8888/` as a script source should give you a hint :)

Comment: I'm running my site on mamp dude... All of my file sources start with http://localhost:8888/ and hasn't been a problem thus far. But just to make sure, I double checked it. The script loads up fine...

Comment: Yeah, mamp is local. Localhost is local. Your server is not local, it's a remote server. You want to use relative paths : src="/scripts/mousewheel.js"

Comment: Jeremy I'm not sure what you mean by "your server is not local"... This site is not live on the web otherwise I would have just pointed everyone to it. Currently the only way to get to this website is on my computer, by typing in "http://localhost:8888/wordpress/portfolio/" so what do you mean my server is not local? mamp is acting as my local server is it not? I have to go into mamp and turn on both the mysql server and apache server for this site to even display on my computer so...

Comment: the minified jQuery mousewheel is also on my machine. Even changing the paths did not change anything... So I tried downloading the whole jQuery library and sticking it on my machine as well. (Even though I have run other scripts like this and it's never been an issue) but still no luck.

Comment: "not getting called on site" --> "on site" doesn't mean "on a remote server"? Anyway, you NEVER want to call a script or any resource with its absolute path. Use `src="/scripts/myscript.js"` By the way, your fiddle link is non existent

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71050/discussion-between-jeremy-thille-and-digital-brent).

Comment: Ah yes... I forgot to put the fiddle link. But no, I meant I have changed the paths still not working so that isn't the issue.

Comment: I made a fiddle, it works; the page alerts "hello" on mouse wheel. http://jsfiddle.net/s4oq7czt/ Any errors in the console?

Comment: I see you're using Wordpress. Try replacing `jQuery(function ($) {` with `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`, it's a Wordpress trick I've learnt.

Comment: YES!!! ^ That was the whole issue! Problem is solved! If you put it as an answer I'll pick it for you. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hahaha, tricky one, isn't it? I hate wordpress ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you're using Wordpress. Try replacing `jQuery(function ($) {` with `jQuery(document).ready(function($){`, it's a Wordpress trick I've learnt.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that this script

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/wp-content/themes/DigitalBrent/scripts/mousewheel.js"></script>`

loaded correctly?
Try to use relative path to this file like

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/mousewheel.js"></script>`.

Comment: Double checked the script. It's loading fine. Switched to relative path anyway but no luck :(